# printing prime numbers using only loops and if statements

Tags: python-3.x

What’s wrong with this code?

```
import math
y=1
z=y
while z>= 1 and z<1000 :
    z= 2*y + 1
    y=y+1
    for a in range (2,int(math.sqrt(z) + 1)):
        if z%a != 0:
            print(z)
        else:
            break
```

What’s wrong here? I keep getting composite numbers as well in my output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *z* to be a prime number, it must be the case that there does not exist *any* number *a* such that `2 <= a <= sqrt(z)` and *a* is a factor of *z*.  I'd change your code to:

```
import math
y=1
z=y
while z>= 1 and z<1000 :
    z= 2*y + 1
    y=y+1
    if all(z%a != 0 for a in range (2,int(math.sqrt(z) + 1))):
        print(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing a number even if it is not divisible by one number but divisible by another number.

The print should be outside the loop.

```
 import math
 y=1
 z=y
 while z>= 1 and z<1000 :
      z= 2*y + 1
      y=y+1
      flag=0
      for a in range (2,int(math.sqrt(z) + 1)):
          if z%a == 0:
              flag=1
              break
      if flag==0:
          print z
```

Another way to improve your algorithm would be to move in multiples of six and check for numbers that are `multipleofsix-1` and `multiple of six+1` which would give you a much better efficiency. Except for 2 and 3 all other prime numbers could be found out in that range.

Further improvement would require you to maintain an array and store all previous primes and only divide by all primes below the square root of the number which you are checking.

There are still better improvisations like sieve of Eratosthenes and Atkins but these are the most basic that you can implement.

Comment: i couldnt get your flag statement...??? I am a beginner and i onli knw..if statements and while,for loops..

Comment: Flag is just a variable. It stores 0 if the number is indivisible by any of the numbers from a to `range(2,int(math.sqrt(z)+1)`
As soon as one of the number perfectly divides it `if z%a==0` the flag changes to 1.
Only if the flag is 0 is the number printed otherwise it is divisible by some other number and hence not a prime.

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as correct/upvote if you find it useful. That's how this community functions.

Comment: one more question..i want to calculate sum of squares from 1 to n..as in 1*1 +....n*n....using simple algebra i can easily do it....but can i do it in python using only if statements and while and for loops..???? also any good book for coding beginnners..particularly python..thnks in advance for ur help..

Comment: That is a different question than this one. If you do a bit of research you would find that it is easily possible.
First what do you mean by `only for loops and while loops`?
Since that is not a relevant question you could ask it as a separate question or ask me personally in chat.

Comment: I have learnt python upto using if and else statements and for and while loops....any boks u might suggest to learn coding..???

Comment: You could try Learning Python By O'Reilly, its for beginners.
If someone has answered your question please mark it as correct.